# C# Web service array can not be processed by Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have written a web service returning json array . The following function returns the data in List:

```
List<ValPair> result = _service.getAllGroupsTypes(P_ClientID);
        var jsonSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonResult = jsonSerial.Serialize(result);
        return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Client Side code :
   $scope.getAllGroups = function()
    {

```
    var Parameters = { "P_ClientID": 1 };
    $http.post("/SMS/getAllGroups", Parameters)
    .then(function success(response) {
        $scope.received = response.data;
        $scope.names = [{ "name": "G1", "value": "1" }] //Just for test purpose
    })
}
```

On the client side BATARANG is displaying scope variable as:

```
received: [{"Key":"Default Group","Value":"1"}]
names: 
   [  { 
       name: G1
       value: 1
    }  ]
```

Angular is processing the $scope.names in ng-repeat where as not showing any result for $scope.received. As both are array, "names" is hard coded one retrieved from db.

Comment: Did you parse the data? `$scope.received = JSON.parse(response.data)`

Comment: Thanks . Yes i was missing what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this:

```
var Parameters = { "P_ClientID": 1 };
$http.post("/SMS/getAllGroups", Parameters)
.then(function success(response) {
    $scope.received = JSON.parse(response.data);
    $scope.names = [{ "name": "G1", "value": "1" }] //Just for test purpose
})
```

Output will be:

```
received: [
  {   Key:"Default Group",
      Value:"1"}
 ]
//
names: 
[  { 
   name: G1
   value: 1
 }  ]
```